# Which agent in a population is seized?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

In Anylogic, I have a fleet of 20 trucks that upon generation (using the `TransporterFleet` block) are placed in a population called `trucks`. These trucks are seized by a resource agent using a `SeizeTransporter` block. How do I find the index of the truck that has been seized? That is, so I can use `trucks(ind).getX()` for example to retrieve the x coordinate of the truck.

Edit1:
Forgot to mention that I have tried using `self.getIndex()`, but that didn't work as apparently that queries the seize block itself and not the transporter agent. Trying to find the answer, I found using `this.` might be an option, but I'm unsure what `this.` refers to and how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the seized unit as `unit` in some specific places in the SeizeTransporter block.
Check the small lightbulb at the front of the edit box, to see if this reference can be used. For more info, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling

Comment: Thanks @mczandrea. I was able to use 'unit' in the At Seize Transporter action.